# How can I split a semicolon delimited string into separate item from string?

Tags: php

I need to split my string input into an semicolon separate as below.

```
Original String: Loganathan <logu@gmail.com>; Nathan <nathan@gmail.com>; Tester <tester@gmail.com>;
```

I need split like

```
Loganathan, logu@gmail.com
Nathan, nathan@gmail.com
Tester, tester@gmail.com
```

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Use `Explode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Post your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` function. [explode link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "Loganathan <logu@gmail.com>; Nathan <nathan@gmail.com>; Tester <tester@gmail.com>;";
$str = str_replace(array(" <",">"),array(", ",""),$str);
$converted = explode(";",$str);
print_r($converted);
```

Which gives you output like

```
Array(
    [0] => Loganathan, logu@gmail.com
    [1] => Nathan, nathan@gmail.com
    [2] => Tester, tester@gmail.com
)
```

Comment: For me email is not displayed

Comment: Because of `<` & `>`, browser consider this as a html tag, so when you will see source code in browser you can see, and to display in browser you have to replace this with blank @logudotcom

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode`

```
$str = 'Loganathan <logu@gmail.com>; Nathan <nathan@gmail.com>; Tester <tester@gmail.com>;';
//Removing the "<>" symbols
$str = str_replace("<",",",$str);
$str = str_replace(">","",$str);    
$result = explode(";", $str);    

print_r(array_filter($result)); //Removing empty array values
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Loganathan ,logu@gmail.com
    [1] =>  Nathan ,nathan@gmail.com
    [2] =>  Tester ,tester@gmail.com        
)
```